# Background-image transition not support in firefox?

Tags: html, css, browser

```
-webkit-transition:background-image 0.6s ease-in;       
   -moz-transition:background-image 0.6s ease-in;
     -o-transition:background-image 0.6s ease-in;
        transition:background-image 0.6s ease-in;
```

On the above code, I've already tried safri,firefox and chrome, ONLY firefox doesn't work. I checked on the web, people say firefox is not support this, but I just want to be make sure, are there any other methods can be done in firefox, or else I have to create a javascript controlled animation just for firefox.

Comment: Did you set `transition-property` to `all`?

Comment: yes I tried to change it to 'all' but firefox still won't work,it just skipped the transition animation and changed the background

Comment: What kind of background image are you transitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN, `background-image` transitions are not supported yet. However, you can fall back to using image sprites and animating the `left` property if you want sliding, or layers of images and animating the `opacity` property.